# Saving data within an .exe

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

I want to create a simple WinForms or WPF application in C#, that manages some data (strings and integers).

What I do not know is where should I store this data so that when I close the program and reopen it, the data will still be there. Same goes for deleting.

I know I could make an adjacent file(xml, txt or similar) but I wish to keep it to one file only. Does Visual Studio have any feature I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save your data in the application settings files it is very simple to use.
double-click on your application properties and open the settings menu. Here the definition of variables and use it as follows code

To write

YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.YourVariable = value;
YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

To read

TempVariable = YourProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.YourVariable;

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for that! Is there a way to create new property settings within the code? Because if it's only creatable by hand in VS then it's useless since I wont be able to add and remove data.

Comment: @tomiG Definitely. Look through MSDN for more information on that. They have some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store data and commit changes directly in the executable file. I suggest you take a look at the ConfigurationManager namespace and save your values in yourExecutableName.config file.

Some resources to start with;

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647832.aspx)

[Example1](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/)

[Example2](https://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/)

Comment: Not exactly true, there are ways to perform some hackery in order to do this. It's extremely ill-advised though, especially in the high level environment that C# operates in.